# Regex for date-validation does not work as expected

Tags: java, regex, date, validation

I want to verify that a date is correctly formatted from user input. I cannot figure out how to include whitespace in my Regex and accept two different types of formats.

### Example

Here are the two correct formats:

1. `April 30, 2021`
2. `04/30/2021`

Those should be matched by the regex in below code.

### Code

```java
public GeoCountDownTimer(String geoDate) {

    for (int i = 0; i < geoDate.length(); i++) {
        if (!String.valueOf(geoDate.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]")) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect formatting at: " + geoDate.charAt(i) + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But your `geoDate.matches` is operating on the whole string every iteration ?

Comment: Super, you added the examples. Now, please add (1) the issue, unexpected behavior/output or error-message resulting from your code, (2) a concrete question. Then we can reopen this great question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like date validation and parsing.
This can be solved using distinct approaches:

1. (high-level) date-parsing functions (e.g. `java.text.DateFormat`)
2. (low-level) regular-expressions (regex)

I would strongly recommend the first, because it is more exact and well-tested, plus communicates intent to peers.

#### Using Java's date-formats

See [Parse a String to Date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446420/parse-a-string-to-date-in-java), using [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```java
String geoDate = "January; 21 2022":

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM; dd yyyy");
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(geoDate);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: for interpreting the month-name according the expected locale (e.g. "January" for *US-en*) you can specify a `Locale` to the constructor: [`SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)).

#### Using regex

Research for similar questions like:
[Trying to improve regex for date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853298/trying-to-improve-regex-for-date-validation)

A simple regex could look like this (only matching, now capture-groups for extraction):

```java
String geoDate = "January; 21 2022":

String regex_alphanum = "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+";  // added a space
System.out.println(geoDate.matches(regex_alphanum)); // does not match because semicolon

String regex_alphanum_semicolon = "[a-zA-Z0-9 ;]+"; // added the semicolon
System.out.println(geoDate.matches(regex_alphanum_semicolon)); // matches
```

Note:  the quantifier (`+`) added to the character-range matches at least one or many occurrences.

**Disadvantage:** Even a tuned regex would probably match `"Mey; 99 0021"` which is not a valid date or allow input for a date that does not exist like `"February, 29 2022"` (2022 is not a leap year).

Comment: I think I am going to go with the `SimpleDateFormat` option, seems a bit easier and better for my use case. How would I have this work with two separate formats  without using some sort of choice variable by the user denoting which format they plan on using so I can call the appropriate method?

Comment: @EthanOnweller Please clarify your question first: (a) state the problem with your code and (b) ask this question there. This way your question helps other users and can be reopened to get further answers ️

Answer (score 1):

> am trying to exclude everything but a-z, 0-9 and spaces

That'll work for any string containing `letters`, `digits`, `spaces` and semicolons (you didn't mention any punctuation but there's a `;` in your example `"January; 21 2022"`).

```
geoDate.matches("[\\w\\s;]+")
```

But if `geoDate` has a fixed structure I'd suggest you use this condition instead:

```
geoDate.matches("\\p{Alpha}{3,9}; \\d{2} \\d{4}")
```

**Character classes** that are used above:

`\p{Alpha}` - an alphabetic character

`\w` - a word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

`\d` - a digit: [0-9]

`\s` - a whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

And `{}` - is a **quantifier**, that allows to specify a number of matches.

`X{n,m}` - X, at least n but not more than m times

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: This looks like it solves my issue, but I am marking the answer above as the selected answer because it offers an easier solution to Regex that I was unaware of.